# Shortcut to run an msc application with a space

Tags: windows, shortcuts

I'm trying to run Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) which is installed on a Windows Server 2012 server.  I have installed Remote Server Administration Tools so I can run WSUS on my Windows 8.1 PC.  Everytime I go into it I have to hold shift and do a "Run as a different user" so I can log in with my administrator credentials.  I would like to create a shortcut so I don't always have to do that.  I achieved what I wanted with a shortcut to Active Directory with this shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /SAVECRED /user:DOMAIN\administrator "c:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\dsa.msc"
```

That works perfectly but now when I try to do that with WSUS using this command

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /SAVECRED /user:DOMAIN\administrator "c:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe C:\Program Files\Update Services\AdministrationSnapin\wsus.msc"
```

I get this error:

```
MMC Cannot open the file C:\Program
```

I know the issue is it is not seeing the full file path because there is a space and it needs quotes around location.  I've tried adding quotes but then I just get errors explaining how to use the RUNAS command.

Is there a way I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is answered over on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281238/cmd-and-mmc-with-whitespace-paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every folder/path has an alternative path, for example `Program Files` is also the same as `PROGRA~1`

So first you must find what the alternative path is for the Update Services folder.
Open **cmd** prompt and navigate to `C:\Program Files\`. Type `dir /x` to list all folders, including the alternative path. Change your **Update Services** folder in the shortcut with the alternative path name.

The old one

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /SAVECRED /user:DOMAIN\administrator "c:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe C:\PROGRA~1\Update Services\AdministrationSnapin\wsus.msc"
```

The new one, for example if Update Services' alternative path is UPDATE~1

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /SAVECRED /user:DOMAIN\administrator "c:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe C:\PROGRA~1\UPDATE~1\AdministrationSnapin\wsus.msc"
```

Note: I don't have an that folder on my computer so you better check yourself. *UPDATE~1* was just an example.

Comment: Thanks! That was it!  You were also right with it being UPDATE~1

Comment: Wonderful! Good to hear :)